# Call reference #name from component from another component Angular 6 + NgbModal Bootstrap

Tags: angular, reference, ng-bootstrap, angular6

I have a component with the NgBModal pop-up window. How can I refer to his reference from any other component?

Component pop-up:

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {NgbModal} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
    selector: 'lol-feedback',
    templateUrl: './feedback.component.html'
})
export class FeedbackComponent implements OnInit {

    private modalTitle: string;

    constructor (private modalService: NgbModal) {}
    ngOnInit() {}

    feedBack(title: string, modal) {
        this.modalTitle = title;
        this.modalService.open(modal, {centered: true});
    }
}
```

Template pop-up:

```
<ng-template #feedbackModal>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <h2 class="feed-title">{{modalTitle}}</h2>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

Another Component, where I try call this pop-up:

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {FeedbackComponent} from '../../system/feedback/feedback.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'lol-footer',
  templateUrl: './footer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./footer.component.scss']
})
export class FooterComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private feedBackComp: FeedbackComponent) {}

    ngOnInit() {}

    feedBack(title: string) {
        this.feedBackComp.feedBack(title, this.feedBackComp.feedbackModal);
    }

}
```

Template another Component:

```
<div class="wrapper footer">
    (....)
</div>
<lol-feedback></lol-feedback>
```

This code not work and i have no idea, how i can to call the window.. @ViewChild maybe? But my attempts to use @ViewChild did not lead to a working result.

Comment: what is not working? do you receive an error?

Comment: @firegloves Property 'feedbackModal' does not exist on type 'FeedbackComponent'. - its error text in terminal

Comment: @ngfelixl Maybe you have any ideas?) I would be extremely grateful)

Comment: why are you passing a template to it's container component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confusing [template input variables](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-input-variable) and [template reference variables](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ref-vars).

If you define a template reference variable like #feedbackModal keep in mind that its scope is limited to the template.

You can't access it into a Component like you are trying.

I think `@ViewChild` is the correct way.
I post an example to refer to child view, based on angular 6 Tour of heroes tutorials:

HeroSearchComponent

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Observable, ObservableLike, Subject} from 'rxjs';
import { debounceTime, distinctUntilChanged, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { HeroService } from '../hero.service';
import { Hero } from '../heroes/hero';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-hero-search',
  templateUrl: './hero-search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./hero-search.component.css']
})
export class HeroSearchComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('childOne')
  private elChildOne: ElementRef;

  heroes$: Observable<Hero[]>;
  private searchTerms = new Subject<string>();

  constructor(private heroService: HeroService) { }

  search(term: string): void {
    this.searchTerms.next(term);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.heroes$ = this.searchTerms.pipe(

      switchMap((term: string) => this.heroService.searchHeroes(term))
    );
  }
}
```

HeroSearchComponent template

```
<div id="search-component">

  <h4>Hero Search</h4>

  <input #searchBox id="search-box" (keyup)="search(searchBox.value)" />

  <ul class="search-result">
    <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes$ | async">
      <a routerLink="/detail/{{ hero.id }}">{{ hero.name }}</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div #childOne>hi son!</div>
```

DashboardComponent

```
import { Component, ViewChild, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Hero } from '../heroes/hero';
import { HeroSearchComponent } from '../hero-search/hero-search.component';
import { HeroService } from '../hero.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  heroes: Hero[] = [];

  @ViewChild(HeroSearchComponent)
  private heroSearch: HeroSearchComponent;

  constructor(private heroService: HeroService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getHeroes();
  }

  getHeroes(): void {

    console.log(this.heroSearch);

    this.heroService.getHeroes().subscribe(heroes => this.heroes = heroes.slice(1, 5));
  }

}
```

DashboardComponent template

```
<h3>Top Heroes</h3>
<div class="grid grid-pad">
  <a *ngFor="let hero of heroes" class="col-1-4" routerLink="/detail/{{hero.id}}">
    <div class="module hero">
      <h4>{{hero.name}}</h4>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>

<app-hero-search></app-hero-search>
```

As you can see you can add a `ViewChild` for your sub component, then there you can add a `ViewChild` of type `ElementRef` to target your markup.

if you debug `console.log(this.heroSearch);` you can see that inside that variabile you can access also elChildOne

Comment: Work! Thank you for helping me understand the principle of `ViewChild`! But this method works only if the selector is placed inside the template of the parent component. Is there a way to place the selector once inside the base component, but access it from several components at once? For example, the `app-modal` component is inside the `app-component`, and another `app-second` component is also inside the `app-component` - how I can call `ElementRef` of the `app-modal` from the `app-second`?

Comment: I think by the way illustrated that selector instantiate a variable that is passable as other variables. You can expose a method in the app-component that call the app-modal and return desired var